# Get index of anchor/hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, indexing

I'm killing my self here.

When I type in index.html#about (or favorite it and open it) i want to get the index() of this, and insert it in the below script as "slideNumber".

Markup

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="frontpage">
    <div id="About">
    <div id="Contact">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () { //detect hash change
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1); //hash to string (= "myanchor")
    $('.slideshow').cycle(slideNumber); //Slideshow-number
});
```

"#about" would be 2 and "#contact" would be 3 and so on.

How do I do this??

Comment: In your selector, are you sure you want to use '.slideshow' which is selecting elements w/ the class="slideshow" or you want to use '#slideshow' to get the id="slideshow"...?

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery ".index()" function?

Comment: @Kchau: Yes
@Pointy: Yes, that is what I want to use. But I can't seem to get it to work. I think I'm missing something fundemental. How can I get the Index() of: "window.location.hash.slice(1)" ?? That's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this should work on the page load:

```
if(window.location.hash != undefined) {
  var slideNumber = $(window.location.hash).index() + 1;
}
```

If you're navigating through the page, you can do your bind and do the index() call inside so that when the hash changes, it'll update:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () { //detect hash change
    var slideNumber = $(window.location.hash).index(); //slideNumber
    $('.slideshow').cycle(slideNumber); //Slideshow-number
});
```

Comment: What if i want it to be activated if you type in index.html#contact ??? Your solution doesn't do this, only if you are on the page to start with.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, that first code snippet I have could be thrown into a .ready() block so that on page load, it'll run that and give you the slideNumber.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
var slideNumber = $("div#" + window.location.hash.slice(1)).prevAll().length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
slides = {frontpage: 1, about: 2, contact: 3};
$('.slideshow').cycle(slides[hash]);
```

To make it dynamic you could use something like this, I guess:

```
$('#slideshow>div').each(function(i) {
  if(this.id == hash) {
    $('.slideshow').cycle(i);
  }
}
```

or

```
$('.slideshow').cycle($('#slideshow>div').index(hash) + 1);
```

Comment: I would like to make it dynamic, so I don't need to write page titles. How can I get the Index() of this: window.location.hash.slice(1) ??? alert(window.location.hash.slice(1).index()); doesn't work...